# JQuery Ajax post request with node.js and express

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, post, express

I was trying to make AJAX post request with JQuery to my Node.JS server in Node.JS and Express, but it doesn't works!

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
app.listen(8888);

app.configure(function(){

   app.use(express.bodyParser());
   app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
   app.use(express.cookieParser());
   app.use(app.router);

});

app.get('/', function (req, res){

   res.render('ajax.ejs');

});

app.post('/ajax', express.bodyParser(), function (req, res){

   console.log(req);
   console.log('req received');
   res.redirect('/');

});
```

And this is the `ajax.ejs`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $('#enter').click(function(){  

     $.ajax({ 
           url: '/ajax',
           type: 'POST',
           cache: false, 
           data: { field1: 1, field2: 2 }, 
           success: function(data){
              alert('Success!')
           }
           , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
               alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
           }
        })
     });            

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
   <input type="button" id="enter" value="Enter">
</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

When the `ajax.ejs`is loaded, there isn't any output in the console, so, the post request didn't work. What can I do?

Thanks advance!

Comment: move express.bodyParser() to the app.use() section: app.use(express.bodyParser()); The body of the post you can retrieve via req.body.

Comment: Done! So, I change `console.log(req);` to `console.log(req.body);`. But the post request stills no working, I don't have any output in the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found your problem. You need to move your script from your head to your body (after the form tag):

```
...
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $('#enter').click(function(){  
   ...

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

The below code works as per the new releases.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedparser = bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false})

app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.cookieParser());

app.get('/', function (req, res){
   res.render('ajax.ejs');
});

app.post('/ajax', urlencodedparser, function (req, res){  
   console.log(req);
   console.log('req received');
   res.redirect('/');

});

app.listen(8888);
```

**ajax.ejs**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>    

</head>
<body>

<form>
   <input type="button" id="enter" value="Enter">
     <script type="text/javascript">

      $('#enter').click(function(){  

     $.ajax({ 
           url: '/ajax',
           type: 'POST',
           cache: false, 
           data: { field1: 1, field2: 2 }, 
           success: function(data){
              alert('Success!')
           }
           , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
               alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
           }
        })
     });            

</script>
</form>

</body> 
</html>
```